# UserControls in the View

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I want to change a WPF project into MVVM pattern. I would like to have 2 usercontrols in view so I can reuse them later. If my mainwindow is the view with 2 usercontrols layed out in a dockpanel, do I need to have 2 viewmodels? Also what would be the right way to setup the usercontrols? Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

You could have one ViewModel, two ViewModels, or many, many ViewModels.  You can think of the ViewModels as representing some kind of logical object or the data underlying a screen, or something that should be processed, serialised or cached separately.. it doesn't matter so long as you put a little thought into it.

A good starting point would be to consider what you are displaying/editing/working with.  If the two UCs are views on the same data (for instance, like a code editor/preview window), you might have one ViewModel.  If the two UCs are showing completely separate data, you might have two.  If one of the UCs has 5 tab pages and shows lots of different data, it should probably bind to more than one.

If you can give a little more information about what you're doing, we can give an answer.  As it stands any answer that gives an exact number based on your current question will be jumping the gun.

Comment: Good answer, but don't forget you can also have no UserControl ViewModels if your UserControl's are only there for defining the way an object looks and behaves. For example, I have a UserControl that is a custom `PopupPanel` and it doesn't rely on a ViewModel since it is just a wrapper for another control

Comment: I have a window with a stackpanel on the left. In that panel is a listbox where a user can add and delete names.There are also buttons to open pages(each page needs the user to enter info)in the frame on the right side of the window.I thought the stackpanel should be uc:1 and the grid that holds the frame should be uc:2

Answer (score 0):

If they are different, then yes you should have a ViewModel for each. If they are clones, then they need only one ViewModel. [This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx#id0090030) is a fantastic resource for learning the MVVM pattern. It is a bit old, but it covers the pattern very nicely for beginners. I have been using it myself over the last few weeks.

Comment: Thank-you for the article i have read that, a bit advanced for me but I will work on relay commands!

Comment: It is definitely a lot all at once. Coming from WinForms, I had to read this article several times while building my first app. That said, I didn't find anything else online nearly as helpful or comprehensive.

Comment: Tyrsius I watched a Windows Client.net MVVM video by Todd Miranda and that really helped explain MVVM and now the article you sent me to makes more sense.   Bety

Comment: Good, glad you are making progress!

Answer (score 0):

This really depends on you usercontrols, but it is possible to have only one viewmodel fo the containing view, and simply bind properties from it to specific properties on the usercontrols

Comment: This is not true. It is possible to have a View with one viewmodel host a usercontrol that uses a different viewmodel.

Comment: I didn't say it wasn't possible, I just said it is not a must

Comment: Misunderstood then, "you can have only one" sounded like you meant not possible.

Comment: Thank-You, I have read about bloating the viewmodel but this is really a small app so maybe one viewmodel would be ok.

Answer (score 0):

Well, since you're going to be reusing the user controls elsewhere then they should each have a viewmodel associated with them. This way when it's time to re-use them, you don't have to rewrite the code again.